# Erro na Chave estrangeira ao apagar um registo

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela com produtos e outra com a categoria desse produto. Na tabela categoria tenho um detailsView com um botão apagar, e apaga quando uma categoria não está associado a um produto (da outra tabela), ou seja quando uma categoria estiver associado a um produto e der o erro, em vez de o utilizador visualizar a pagina de erro, quero que apareça um aviso de erro numa pagina ou numa label, qualquer coisa que o utilizador perceba porque não pode apagar a categoria.

erro:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_Produtos_Categorias". The conflict occurred in database
>   "C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO
>   2013\WEBSITES\PROJECTO\APP_DATA\DBTI2.MDF", table "dbo.Produtos",
>   column 'IDCategoria'.
>       The statement has been terminated.

Comment: já que tu quer que a gente faça o teu trabalho, vai dar uma parte do teu salário para quem o fizer?

Comment: Olha que é uma pergunta legítima de um programador júnior. Se não quer ajudar simplesmente ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O error 574 penso que não existe. Resolvi o problema desta forma:

Ficheiro Web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPages/Oopss.aspx" />   
  </customErrors>
```

pagina de erro

`ErrorPage="~/ErrorPages/Oopss.aspx"` na directiva @page

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tratar pelo código do erro, 574 nesse caso (pelo o que olhei rapidamente aqui, teste aí):

```
try
{
   // seu comando...
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 574)
    {
        // Seu tratamento
    }
    throw;
}
```